# From WiFi to Cellular 3/4G on ESP32

Tags: esp32, arduino-c++

I am building a project utilizing Wifi on the ESP32 module. Using RTOS, I am running a web server on 1 core and a web client on another core. This works very well and I can access the web server remotely via my browser and the WiFi provided IP address. The Web client reads some sensors and sends the data via WiFi to my database. All good and everything works as desired.

Now I need to do the next step and move beyond the reach of the WiFi and reproduce the same result via 3/4G cellular. I looked at the "easy" solution to use an industrial 3/4G WiFi router and simply keep what I have. Cost of these "industrial" type routers are on the high side, where as 3/4G module which also include a GPS chip are around half or less. Problem is that I cannot get my head around how I will "replace" my current WiFi functionality with one of these modules. The modules seems to expect you to connect via serial (rs232) and using modem AT commands establish a connection to the internet. Question is, after connecting to the internet, how do you continue to have "network functionality" same as with the built-in WiFi? Is there some library that will do ethernet over the serial port? Can I still have the WiFi and the "serial ethernet" running at the same time or switch between the two?

Thanks!

Comment: So after many hours of search, I found this https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/tools/sdk/include/lwip/netif/ppp/pppos.h  So PPPos is implemented on the ESP32 Arduino environment. If I can just find an example to use it... :)

Comment: There are GSM libraries in the Arduino IDE, some of them actually support PPPos functionality. There are even sample code under examples, INCOMPATIBLE, GSM, and yes, there seems to be compiler problems like :"fatal error: avr/pgmspace.h: No such file or directory #include <avr/pgmspace.h>" 
There are a few links from the library page to their websites, but I haven't had any time to explore yet. Think it is time to order a 4g/IoT GSM shield...